# undefined reference to `PDC_ungetch' while other functions work in PDcurses

Tags: c, cmake, ncurses, undefined-reference, pdcurses

i'm having a strange problem where i get `undefined reference to "PDC_ungetch"` while I can use without any problem other functions from curses.h, for example:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(){
    initscr();
    int ch = getch();
    ungetch(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

With this code i only get `undefined reference to "PDC_ungetch"` while `initscr()` works with no problems, what would be the problem?

My CMake is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(rogue)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c gamelib.c gamelib.h maze.c maze.h) //these are other files I use

find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(rogue ${SOURCE_FILES} gamelib.c gamelib.h maze.c maze.h) //Same here

target_link_libraries(rogue ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What's introducing the alias of `ungetch` to `PDC_ungetch`? Please show us the *complete* source to your test program, including any `#include`s.

Comment: please read `http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO`  and similar pages, which show there is no function: `init_curses()`

Comment: @user3629249 I'm sorry, i called the wrong function, I edited the source but the problem it's still the same.

Comment: @duskwuff [PDcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/doc/PDCurses.txt) here says that `getch` and `ungetch` are defined as macros, so I think that it's trying to call `PDC_ungetch` trough the macro. You can find the macro [here](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/curses.h). 
This is all the source code I used for the problem to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the header file `<curses.h>` from PDCurses, that particular function is the only one treated in that way: defining a macro to use the function with a `PDC_` prefix.

If you happen to be cross-compiling (from Cygwin for example), and if the `cmake` macros are not setup/used properly, they could find the system curses library, which does not use that naming convention.  In that case, you would get just that one error when trying to link.

Comment: I'm using MinGW, but I didn't understand what should I do to fix the problem, is the  `cmake` not set correctly? If yes, what's the problem? I posted my cmake setup.

Comment: I was advising you to find what the actual library was that was used for linking.  It may not be PDCurses.

Comment: Maybe I found something useful, i found [this](https://github.com/aevalo/aeirc/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindPDCurses.cmake), probably the problem is that, in the `cmake`, I look for `Curses` and not `PDCurses` and in order to look for the latter one I should use something like the one I linked before. The problem is: I don't know how, I'm fairly new to `cmake` do you have any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: You could copy the whole macro to your sources and use it (a quick read doesn't show issues).  Your question lists the macro calls but does not show the actual library name on your system.